# Silverlight Binding to TranslateX

Tags: silverlight, binding, windows-phone-7

I have a simple winphone7 application, but I think this would apply to any silverlight.

Basically I have an ellipse and I would like to move it with the translate X and Y properties.  Here is my attempt:

```
<Ellipse Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Margin="0,0,-3,-3" Stroke="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform TranslateY="{Binding Y}" TranslateX="{Binding X}"/>
            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
</Ellipse>
```

I am pretty sure the Binding is set correctly; The problem is it gives me this error when I run the application:

2260 An error has occurred. [Line: 4 Position: 33]

which is a XAML error.  The error goes away when I comment out the composittransform line.

Can anyone point me in a right direction? If you need more code let me know, i'll post more up.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 is currently based on the Silverlight 3 runtime not Silverlight 4.

One of the limitations in Silverlight 3 is that you can only bind to an element that derives from `FrameworkElement`.  The transform classes do not derive from `FrameworkElement` and hence cannot participate in binding.

Instead of moving the ellipse via binding consider using a `Storyboard` to animate the transform instead.

Comment: ah, thanks for that. I will give some storyboard things a try when I get home this evening.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones, was this limitation removed in Silverlight 4, which comes with Mango?

Comment: @altso: Thats a very good question.  Certainly in the desktop version of Silverlight 4 you can bind to Dependency objects.  By extension I would expect to see that in Mango, however, I haven't tested that to be sure.