# Binding to 'To' In Storyboard

Tags: silverlight, binding, windows-phone-7

I'll try to make this as simple as I can.

I want to do this:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="MoveToLocation">
   <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="{Binding X}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
</Storyboard>
```

As you may have noticed the Binding on 'To' Property does not work.  It seems to only accept static values.

How does one do this animation with MVVM? I cant just put in static data, cause it's going to change.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DoubleAnimation` is also not a `FrameworkElement` hence binding doesn't work to that either.  See my answer to your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984788/silverlight-binding-to-translatex).

In order to achieve your goal here you will need to take the contents of your `DataTemplate` and turn it into a `UserControl`.   This new control can then expose a set of dependency properties that you need to bind to, including one for `To` value of the storyboard.

Comment: That second paragraph is what I needed you to elaborate on, thanks.  I will try this when I get home this evening.  So are you suggesting I should contain a Storyboard instance inside the object itself (not in the xaml)? Seems kinda strange, but If that's what I have to do, then I'll do it.

Comment: I guess I'm still a little confused - I could wrap this whole 'object' into a usercontrol and create my own Property called 'To', thats fine.  However, somewhere, i'll still need to set (and set again) the property of 'To' in my storyboard - which, like you said, is not bindable.

Comment: @Peanut:  Once you have created a UserControl to encapsultate this specific peice of UI behaviour you can manipulate the control with "code-behind" directly.  Sometimes binding just isn't the answer and you actually have to write code that does the job.

Comment: Interesting.  It seems as if the MVVM approach is still a little immature then.  I think I have the information to mark this as the answer.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do it in a Style, that's why it's not working. Silverlight will Freeze it because it's shared across all instances of that style.

Try putting it in the element itself and that should work.

Comment: sorry for not showing enough code, but it's not in a style. It is, however, in a DataTemplate.  (I'm going to have lots of instances of objects that need to be animated)