# What does this mean? "Cannot convert the value in attribute 'XXX' to object of type '(no type)'"

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to bind a property, and I'm getting the most inexplicable error message.

```
Cannot convert the value in attribute 'To' to object of type ''
```

Yep, the destination type is an empty string.

This is brought on by this line:

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
    To="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}" Duration="0:0:0.6"
    FillBehavior="HoldEnd" AutoReverse="False"/>
```

I'm thoroughly perplexed.  How can the destination type be... unspecified?  If it can't figure out the destination type, how can it even attempt to convert?  **How can it not know the destination type?**

If I change it to a number, say, `To="90"`, then it works fine.  I guess it knows what type it's supposed to be there.

Anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a partial answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002421/binding-to-to-in-storyboard).

A DoubleAnimation is not a FrameworkElement, thus binding is not supported.  (I've seen that binding to a StaticResource will work, since it's static, but non-static bindings will fail.)

So I think this may just be a wonky error message.

I'm marking this as the answer, but if anyone has a better one, please go ahead.  I'll gladly mark your answer as correct if it's better than this one.